# Error writing R dataframe to hadoop using RODBC

Tags: r, hadoop, hive, rodbc

I am trying to use RODBC to upload a small dataset to hadoop.

However it returns the following error. My data is just a small 3 rows with 2 columns. I have tested my hadoop ODBC connection and it definitely works.

```
library(RODBC)
hivechannel <- odbcConnect("HADOOP",uid="user",pwd="pwd")
```

This is the sample data

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
state <- c('NSW','VIC','NSW')
dat <- data.frame(employee,state)
```

The query being passed

```
sqlSave(hivechannel,dat,table="DATALIB.DATATEST",rownames=F)
```

The error code that I received

```
Error in sqlSave(hivechannel, dat, table = "DATALIB.DATATEST",  : 
HY000 80 [Hortonworks][Hardy] (80) Syntax or semantic analysis error thrown 
in server while executing query. Error message from server: Error while 
compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:40 cannot recognize input 
near '"employee"' 'varchar' '(' in column specification
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE DATALIB.DATATEST  
("employee" varchar(255), "state" varchar(255))'
```

Any suggestion or tips? for info, I did similar sqlSave methodology to write to Teradata and it works so I thought Hadoop ODBC would have been very similar....

Comment: can you show the query being passed in?

Comment: `varchar` datatype isn't supported, if you are using a hive version before 0.12.0..that might be the reason for the error..use `string` datatype instead.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala this is the query being passed sqlSave(hivechannel,dat,table="DATALIB.DATATEST",rownames=F)

Comment: Just tried this and this doesn't work sqlSave(hivechannel,dat,table="DATALIB.DATATEST",rownames=F,varTypes = c(employee="STRING",state="STRING"))